# hibernate which naming strategy is default

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, jboss6.x

When researching how to implement a custom naming strategy (for table names only) I stumbled upon an inconsistency, which I can't resolve.
(I'm using hibernate-core 3.6.6.Final on JBoss 6.1.0.Final with PostgreSQL 9.1.9)

There seem to be three builtin implementations for `NamingStrategy`:

1. `DefaultNamingStrategy`
2. `EJB3NamingStrategy`
3. `ImprovedNamingStrategy`

The default seems to be set to `EJB3NamingStrategy` in `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`.

However the table names seem to be set according to a strategy, that matches none of the above.

Example:
Class name: `package.ClassName`
Resulting table name: `classname`

Strategies 1 and 2 simply call `StringHelper.unqualify( className )` which simply removes all package names and dots, so the result should be `ClassName`.

Strategy 3 removes all package names and dots, then puts an underscore before each camelcased letter and finally converts to lowercase, which should yield `class_name`.

(Source code of hibernate 4.1.0.Final seems to be unchanged in these classes.)

Could anyone help me clarify this?

Answer (score 5):

Very easy! Because I don't want to spend time to create toy environment with `hibernate-core 3.6.6.Final` I give you instruction how to check which instance used **EXACTLY IN YOUR WORKING APPLICATION**.

Install `visualvm` on your host. It allow to create heap dump for local application. To create heap dump on remove server - run on server:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.dump $PID
```

Open dump in `visualvm` and run OQL query:

```
map(heap.objects('org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration'), "it.namingStrategyDelegator")
```

That is **YOUR NAMING STRATEGY**. You may use "Instance" tab to navigate across reference hierarchy to get known what other actual types of `hbm` or `jpa` NamingStrategy is used.

Different version of Hibernate have different declared fields and types. If there are no `namingStrategyDelegator` field try digging to instance:

```
heap.objects('org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration')
```

If that class isn't in your version of Hibernate - try read docs and sources and find appropriate class.

With dependency `org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final` I have:

```
map(heap.objects('org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration'), "it.namingStrategyDelegator")
      == org.hibernate.cfg.naming.LegacyNamingStrategyDelegator
```

and it uses internally:

```
LegacyHbmNamingStrategyDelegate
LegacyJpaNamingStrategyDelegate
```

depending on presents of JPA annotations. In any cases this instances reference to `LegacyNamingStrategyDelegator` (yea, cyclic references!) which have field `namingStrategy` with instance of `org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy`.

That all! I spend 1 min to find default naming strategy implementation in my wepapp and 5 min to write this post ((

Thanks for watching, happy hacking!